# Robust encoding of data into visual image

Tags: image-processing, image-compression

I have an app which lets users download presets as ~10kB of data and share them.  There's no web-service or anything, it's just posting files and stuff.

Bandwidth and storage space aren't so tight in the modern world, so (for fun, because it's a creative app) I'd like to provide an option to download the data as an image.

Is there a way to encode data into the pixels themselves, such that it can be recovered even if the image is resized a bit and JPEG-encoded? (Maybe colour-space nonsense as well.)

(Anything that requires bit-perfect copies wouldn't work for sharing on social media etc., and if it needs to be an exact copy then you might as well stuff it in a custom metadata chunk.)

I've found some stenography-related stuff, but they're geared towards hiding things in details we can't see.  I kind of want to opposite - using the features we *can* see because that seems more likely to be preserved by image compression.

(*Edit to clarify*: I'm looking for a solution to store the actual data, and it shouldn't require an internet connection to work.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Classic Methods

Assuming the images are 8 bit per color than you could, per pixel, assign the last bit of each color for your own data.
For an image of size `M x N x 3` in a column stack data structure you basically have `3MN` bits to encode.

Let's say we encode our symbols using 8 bits, then the question is how much bits to allocate for error correction.
I haven't played with JPEG and such in that context, but you should do some testing. But probably using even simple method you could over come 2-3 bit flips which will give you something like 2-3 bits per byte for your symbols.
If you need more symbols, move to 2 Bytes encoding.

Simple code ot use is the [Hamming Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code).

**Remark** This should handle the JPEF compression and maybe some other transforms yet not a size change. This will be more tricky.

#### Embedding QR Code

There are technologies to embed QR Codes in images which might do what you want.

Something like:

- [Colored-QRNet: Fast QR Code Color Image Embedding](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9909599).
- [Twitter Thread on Generative AI for QR Codes](https://twitter.com/AlexAIDaily/status/1666902617446907905).
  Look how people use [MidJourney](https://www.midjourney.com/) to generate those.
- [HuggingFace QR Code AI Art Generator](https://huggingface.co/spaces/huggingface-projects/QR-code-AI-art-generator).
- [Tutorial - Stable Diffusion tutorial: How to make an AI art with QR code](https://lablab.ai/t/stable-diffusion-tutorial-how-to-make-an-ai-art-with-qr-code).
- [Tutorial: How to generate customized QR codes](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/how-to-generate-customized-qr-codes-5d8337a7b30e).

You could embed the URL in the QR code and then ship it as an image.

Comment: Definitely not looking for an AI solution  sorry, I should've specified.  And QR codes can only hold 3kb max, although I suppose I could embed a little grid of them.

Comment: @cloudfeet, I added a simple idea for a more classic method.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  Since it's not trying to be secret, I could use way more than the bottom bit, perhaps even the whole thing.  And with Reed-Solomon, I could absolutely pack it with error correction.

Comment: For resizing: I could borrow an idea from your QR-code suggestion, like: saying the data always uses a 200-wide grid, regardless of the actual image dimensions.  If each of those grid-squares had 2 bits of data, 4 bits of error-correction (plus the fact that it's averaged over the grid!) and 2 bits for artistic use, a square image would fit 10kB of data in it, and more data could just use a taller image.

Comment: @cloudfeet, For resizing I'd encode the data in specific redundant pixels where some algorithm will run to detect them. There are many ways to do so. Like detection on the `R` channel while the bits on the `G` and `B` channels.

Comment: @cloudfeet, Could you please mark my answer?